# how can i set the background image as SVG

Tags: reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

so i tried to import an SVG background image, it works when i import a PNG or any other type but nothing shown as SVG
and if you know a better idea working with fabric canvas on reactJS please let me know

```
    const Tool = () => {
      const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState("");
      useEffect(() => {
        setCanvas(initCanvas());
      }, []);
      const initCanvas = () =>
        new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
          height: 800,
          width: 800,
    
          backgroundImage: "/images/__Body1.svg", // here is the imported image
        });
    
    
      return (
        <div className="test">
          
    
          <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Container maxWidth="md">
    
              <canvas id="canvas" />
    
            </Container>
          </React.Fragment>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Tool;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `backgroundImage: url(/images/__Body1.svg)`.

Just make sure that the svg file is being included in the resulting folder structure.

If you don't have the `/images/__Body1.svg` file in your output bundle and you want the bundler to handle it, you'll need to likely make some changes. As far as (presumably) webpack can tell, `/images/__Body1.svg` is just a string so it won't copy it over as part of your bundling. If that is the case (svg not added to resulting bundle), you can look at the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images) about updating the `webpack.config.js` file. Note you'll also likely need to manually include the svg file, ie.

```js
import bodySvg from ('/images/__Body1.svg');
//...
  new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
    height: 800,
    width: 800,
    backgroundImage: bodySvg, // here is the imported image
  });
//...
```

[another resource](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/)